# Mental Symphysis

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, embryology, joints

Why dow we consider mandibular symphysis(symphysis menti) as type of Amphiarthrosis that too of symphysis variety, eventhough it lacks movement and cartilage at joint?

Why don't we consider as Synostosis (a type of synarthrosis)?

Comment: Why downvote???

Comment: What is the source saying that the mandibular symphysis is an amphiarthrosis?

Comment: All symphysis are amphiarthrosis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphysis

Comment: Maybe wikipedia is wrong and/or incomplete.

Comment: No, many different sources too say so. See this: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiRwqzUjvzTAhVJP48KHVO6AaQQjhwIBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.highlands.edu%2Facademics%2Fdivisions%2Fscipe%2Fbiology%2Ffaculty%2Fharnden%2F2121%2Fnotes%2Fart.htm&psig=AFQjCNFTkbPWP72aNKaHrWWFUht_we-hqw&ust=1495288708303622

Comment: Lots of vertebrates have unfused mandibular symphyses.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense.